# FB.ui for mobile : how to convert to rul using javascript

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am using FB.ui
Facebook document says it is not working with mobile.

I need to convert them to a url and should redirect to facebook.

```
url = "https://m.facebook.com/dialog/feed?
```

and i need to append all the data to this url.

But i don't know how to convert this to url

```
actions: [{ name: action_name, link: link }],
```